# roscanopen - Transition timeout; Could not enable motor

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

roscanopen's driver initilization service call is failing with error message:

success: False
message: Transition timeout; Could not enable motor

After looking at the source code, it seems like a timeout is occuring when the driver is attempting to change the state of the controller from:
Switch_On_Disabled -> Ready_To_Switch_On -> Switched_On -> Operation_Enable

It is timing out when trying to change the state from Switch_On_Disabled -> Ready_To_Switch_On.

I am able to operate the controller via canbus using the manufacturer's software, and the fact that ros-canopen is able to read the initial state of the controller (Switch_On_Disabled) means that the bus communication is up and running functionally. So i highly doubt this is a hardware issue. The controller im using is a Nanotec N5-5-2 which is DS402.

The steps i took to prepare the driver included changing the control word RPDO transmission type to 1 (every sync), and the status word TPDO transmission type to 1. Also, i added a target velocity RPDO with transmission type 1 and a Current velocity TPDO with transmission type 1 for feedback in order to run the controller in profile velocity mode via ros-canopen.

sudo ip link can0 up type can bitrate 1000000

The baudrate in the controller and Node ID are set to 1Mbps, and 1, respectively (using DIP switches).

The following is the configuration of the driver, and the output of candump after the initialize service is called. I hope someone can spot the issue. I will repeat, transitioning states is functional with the manufacturer's software, but it seems like ros-canopen is failing to get the states changed.

My configuration parameters:

```
bus:

  device: can0

sync:

  interval_ms: 10

  overflow: 0

defaults:

  eds_pkg: my_pkg

  eds_file: "config/N5-2-2.eds"

  vel_to_device: "rint((vel))"

nodes:

  wheel_joint:

  id: 1

joint_names: [fr_wheel_joint]

joint_state_controller:

  type: joint_state_controller/JointStateController

  publish_rate: 50

wheel_joint_velocity_controller:

  type: velocity_controllers/JointVelocityController

  joint: fr_drive_joint

  required_drive_mode: 3
```

More importantly, here is the candump output when the initialization service of ros_canopen is called:

can0  000   [2]  82 01

can0  701   [1]  00

can0  601   [8]  2B 17 10 00 00 00 00 00

can0  581   [8]  60 17 10 00 00 00 00 00

can0  000   [2]  01 01

can0  701   [1]  05

can0  181   [3]  40 06 03

can0  281   [4]  AC FF FF FF

can0  381   [2]  00 00

can0  481   [4]  00 00 00 00

can0  601   [8]  40 61 60 00 00 00 00 00

can0  581   [8]  4F 61 60 00 03 00 00 00

can0  201   [7]  00 01 03 00 00 00 00

can0  601   [8]  40 61 60 00 00 00 00 00

can0  581   [8]  4F 61 60 00 03 00 00 00

can0  080   [0]

can0  181   [3]  40 06 03

can0  481   [4]  00 00 00 00

can0  601   [8]  40 61 60 00 00 00 00 00

can0  581   [8]  4F 61 60 00 03 00 00 00

can0  201   [7]  06 01 03 00 00 00 00

//This Block Repeats for a certain period

can0  080   [0]

can0  181   [3]  40 06 03

can0  481   [4]  00 00 00 00

can0  601   [8]  40 61 60 00 00 00 00 00

can0  581   [8]  4F 61 60 00 03 00 00 00

//

//This Block Repeats for a much longer period

can0  080   [0]

can0  181   [3]  40 07 03

can0  481   [4]  00 00 00 00

can0  601   [8]  40 61 60 00 00 00 00 00

can0  581   [8]  4F 61 60 00 03 00 00 00

//

//This block occurs when the error is returned after timeout.

can0  080   [0]

can0  000   [2]  02 01

can0  181   [3]  40 07 03

can0  481   [4]  00 00 00 00

can0  701   [1]  04

//No more messages on the canbus.

I appreciate all the help with interpreting the candump output..

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/279750/roscanopen---transition-timeout;-could-not-enable-motor/) by [JadTawil](https://answers.ros.org/users/29121/jadtawil/) on ROS Answers with karma: 71 on 2018-01-13

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

SOLVED.

The problem here was that RPOD1 in my controller, which is mapped to the Control Word (6040) and the Mode selection (6060), had the communication paramter "transmission type" set to 1 (every SYNC).

When i changed this back to 0xFF (asynchronous), It worked.

---

Originally posted by [JadTawil](https://answers.ros.org/users/29121/jadtawil/) with karma: 71 on 2018-01-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [YellowShyGuy](https://answers.ros.org/users/51914/yellowshyguy/) on 2020-02-19**:
I know it's been a while but could you elaborate how you managed to do this?

**Comment by [miura](https://answers.ros.org/users/59801/miura/) on 2020-09-29**:
Perhaps it is editing an EDS file.
'ParameterName=Transmission type...' Change the "DefaultValue" of the "ParameterName=Transmission type..." to 255.